# Criteria Join query not binding referenced parameters of association

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria

I have a mapping like this in my `DiningTable` entity

```
@OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "diningTable",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
private List<ReservedSlot> reservedSlots = new ArrayList<>();
```

I am using the below lines to fetch `DiningTable` and `ReservedSlot`

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<DiningTable> cq = cb.createQuery(DiningTable.class);
    Root<DiningTable> root = cq.from(DiningTable.class);

    Join<Object, Object> reservedSlots = (Join<Object, Object>) root.fetch(DiningTable_.RESERVED_SLOTS);

    ParameterExpression<Integer> requestedChair = cb.parameter(Integer.class);
    cq.where(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(reservedSlots.get(ReservedSlot_.AVAILABLE_CHAIR), requestedChair));
```

But when I am passing the paramater like

```
TypedQuery<DiningTable> query = entityManager.createQuery(cq);
query.setParameter(requestedChair, searchCriteria.getRequestedChair());
```

It is throwing exception -

> Cannot create binding for parameter reference [org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.expression.JpaCriteriaParameter@54543570] - reference is not a parameter of this query"

Although biding to root is working fine

```
cq.select(root).where(cb.equal(root.get("tableLocation"), searchCriteria.getTableLocation())); // This works fine
```

Can anyone please point me to the issue ? I am clueless here.

Comment: Also affected. We are using hibernate-core-6.2.1.Final.jar. The error happens seemingly randomly